# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined at displayFull

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble with this homework assignment and I have been stuck on it for a while. I am getting an error message saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined at
>   displayFull

Any idea to fix this?

The image folders and files are in the same folder, so the `src` is right.

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Fig. 12.5: coverviewer.html -->
<!-- Dynamic styles used for animation. -->
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>Deitel Book Cover Viewer</title>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
      <script src = "coverviewer.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "mainimg">
         <img id = "imgCover" src = "fullsize/jhtp.jpg" alt = "Full cover image">
      </div>
      <div id = "thumbs"> // I AM GETTING THE ERROR MESSAGE HERE FOR EACH IMAGE ON CLICK AT WITH THE ONCLICK ATTRIBUTE
         <img src = "thumbs/jhtp.jpg" id = "jhtp" alt = "Java How to Program cover" onclick = "displayFull('jhtp');">
         <img src = "thumbs/iw3htp.jpg" id = "iw3htp" alt = "Internet & World Wide Web How to Program cover" onclick = "displayFull('iw3htp');">
         <img src = "thumbs/cpphtp.jpg" id = "cpphtp" alt = "C++ How to Program cover" onclick = "displayFull('cpphtp');">
         <img src = "thumbs/jhtplov.jpg" id = "jhtplov" alt = "Java How to Program LOV cover" onclick = "displayFull('jhtplov');">
         <img src = "thumbs/cpphtplov.jpg" id = "cpphtplov" alt = "C++ How to Program LOV cover" onclick = "displayFull('cpphtplov');">
         <img src = "thumbs/vcsharphtp.jpg" id = "vcsharphtp" alt = "Visual C# How to Program cover" onclick = "displayFull('vcsharphtp');">
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
var fullpic = new Array(6);

//define each array element as an image
for (var i=0;i<fullpic.length;i++)
    fullpic[i] = new Image(289,373);

//give the path to the src properties of the array elements
fullpic[0].src = "fullsize/jhtp.jpg";
fullpic[0].alt = "Java How to Program";
fullpic[1].src = "fullsize/iw3htp.jpg";
fullpic[2].src = "fullsize/cpphtp.jpg"; 
fullpic[3].src = "fullsize/jhtplov.jpg";
fullpic[4].src = "fullsize/cpphtplov.jpg";
fullpic[5].src = "fullsize/vcsharphtp.jpg";

/*function displayFull(title){
    document.getElementById("imgCover").src="fullsize/"+title+".jpg";

}*/

function displayFull(i){
    document.getElementById("imgCover").src=fullpic[i].src; // I AM GETTING THE ERROR MESSAGE HERE 

}
```

Comment: fullpic is an array, it's "keys" are 0, 1, 2, 3 etc ... you call displayFull with a string argument, that isn't 0, 1, 2, 3 etc so for example, `fullpic['jhtp']` is undefined of course

Comment: @PHPglue - No it doesn't, it makes a new array of length 6 but with no elements.

Comment: @JaromandaX so in the HTML i should use onclick = displayFull(fullpic[])?

Comment: no, you need to pass in a **NUMBER**, 0, 1, 2, etc

Comment: Use an Object if you want to have an Associative Array like thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it cleaner and readable, You can just do something like this as mentioned below. All you need is , have all the images under in your markup.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#thumbs").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

    if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img") {
      var title = event.target.getAttribute("id"),
        imgSrc = "fullsize/" + title + ".jpg",
        imgElement = document.querySelector("#imgCover");

      imgElement.src = imgSrc;
      imgElement.alt = imgSrc;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Fig. 12.5: coverviewer.html -->
<!-- Dynamic styles used for animation. -->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Deitel Book Cover Viewer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="coverviewer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mainimg">
    <img id="imgCover" src="fullsize/jhtp.jpg" alt="Full cover image">
  </div>
  <div id="thumbs">// I AM GETTING THE ERROR MESSAGE HERE FOR EACH IMAGE ON CLICK AT WITH THE ONCLICK ATTRIBUTE
    <img src="thumbs/jhtp.jpg" id="jhtp" alt="Java How to Program cover">
    <img src="thumbs/iw3htp.jpg" id="iw3htp" alt="Internet & World Wide Web How to Program cover">
    <img src="thumbs/cpphtp.jpg" id="cpphtp" alt="C++ How to Program cover">
    <img src="thumbs/jhtplov.jpg" id="jhtplov" alt="Java How to Program LOV cover">
    <img src="thumbs/cpphtplov.jpg" id="cpphtplov" alt="C++ How to Program LOV cover">
    <img src="thumbs/vcsharphtp.jpg" id="vcsharphtp" alt="Visual C# How to Program cover">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```